# Organising Files as per timestamp in python

Tags: python, file, operating-system, organization

Have a task where i have to sort files into groups using their time frames

Suppose i have files like “ *2018/12/12 11:32:34 xyz.txt* “

And the task that i have is That I have to use python to first extract the timeframe from the files and order them into groups by creating directories firstly as per years then as per months and finally the all the files inside their respective years and months

Like for the file in above egs it should be in a path like
*Files/2018/December/file.txt*

Just need help regarding which libraries to use andnd how to approach the problem

Comment: If you are interested in libraries, you need to use stock libraries: `datetime.datetime` to transform your time to DateTime class, and `os` module to create a folder and copy files to the folder. That's all, I think.

Comment: Okay.. just want a few tips on how to approach the problem.... like i have read how to make directories using os but how am i supposed to place the files in the correct directory based on the timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to copy files with timestamp names to the directories. Our input data:

1. Directory with timestamp files
2. Directory, where we need to save our files.

We ask a user to input those directories, and after that, we need to open directory 1 (directory with timestamp files) and read each one step by step.
We can get all filenames in the directory and iterate in like in the list, parse date in filename. We get the first filename and split the filename by space. Now we have a date and a time in the first array element and in the second.
Now we will use the datetime library to transform date and time to datetime. After doing that we can easily get a year, month, day, etc.
Now we can check year and month and create a folder connected with that year and month. If a folder not exists, we can create it. After that - use copy to copy file in that folder

EDIT. My solution:

```
import glob
import os
from datetime import datetime
from shutil import copyfile


def getListOfFilenamesInFolder(src):
    filenamesWithPath = glob.glob(f"{src}\\*.txt")
    filenames = [filename.split('\\')[-1] for filename in filenamesWithPath]
    return filenames


def parseFilename(filename):
    splittedFilename = filename.split(' ')
    dateFilename = splittedFilename[0]
    timeFilename = splittedFilename[1]
    datetimeFilename = datetime.strptime(f'{dateFilename} {timeFilename}', '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S')
    return datetimeFilename



def createFolderIfNotExist(dest, datetimeFilename):
    path = os.path.join(dest, 'File')
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    path = os.path.join(path,  str(datetimeFilename.year))
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    path = os.path.join(path, datetimeFilename.strftime("%b"))
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    return path
    pass


def makeSortingByFilenames(src, dest):
    listOfFilenames = getListOfFilenamesInFolder(src)
    print(listOfFilenames)
    for filename in listOfFilenames:
        datetimeFilename = parseFilename(filename)
        path = createFolderIfNotExist(dest, datetimeFilename)
        copyfile(os.path.join(src, filename), os.path.join(path, ' '.join(filename.split(' ')[2:])))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    srcDirectory = input()
    destDirectory = input()
    makeSortingByFilenames(srcDirectory, destDirectory)
```

I have that structure folder. If you have another filenames, you need to change `datetimeFilename = datetime.strptime(f'{dateFilename} {timeFilename}', '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S')` to your specific filenames.

Screenshots:

My input and output:
[image: My input and output]
Results:

[image: Results]